# font-awesome-rails icon formatting incorrect on heroku

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

[image]
[image]

I'm using font-awesome-rails to generate some icons on my site.  When I run the site locally, the image icons appear correctly (they are styled to be different colors).  However, when I push to production via Heroku, the styling is messed up (some icons don't appear, and none of the icons are the right color).  What could I be doing wrong?  I'm not even sure what could be wrong with my code, so if any particular snippets would be helpful for me to share, let me know and I'll add it.

The image on the left is a snapshop of the website in production, and the image on the right is the website running locally.

**EDIT:**

After restarting my development server, I'm finding the icons appear incorrectly locally as well.  What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it was an issue with my Gemfile; when I checked out an older version of my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, I was able to get rid of the problem.